# Data Transfer From GCS to Google BQ Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

BQ Failed to read csv using Google Data Transfer

Hello everyone, I'm here trying to extract app install from Google Cloud Storage using data transfer feature from BQ. Unfortunately the transfer always fails

Error message:
Job bqts_653655b0-0000-2d84-af91-582429b4ccb8 (table android_app_install_2018) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 100. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://pubsite_prod_rev_0189/stats/installs/app_install.csv

I already set up the destination table using the schema that i got from GCS directly without data transfer (csv downloaded) . I always wonder why does the error always stuck on rows:0 Until I found out that the columns order are somehow generate randomly each time I extract the data.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so i can automatically get the data from GC using BQ Transfer Data

Comment: If your format is not stable, How do you want that BigQuery able to solve that automatically? You could imagine loading the file in a new table every day, perform an insert select in the target table with the field name, and delete the temporary table. It's more a pipeline that a single step ingestion but it should work!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how can i do that with the BQ Data transfer cuz i could not find custom query using Data Transfer BQ UI

Comment: You need to create a pipeline. Nothing out of the box. You can use Cloud Workflow for that